# Fix checkmarx report issue Client DOM XSRF

Tags: checkmarx, xsrf

In vfComponent **parent.location = self.location;** and in checkmarx report it is showing

> "component gets a parameter from a user request URL from element
>   location. This parameter value flows through the code and is
>   eventually used to modify database contents. The application does not
>   require renewed user authentication for the request. This may enable
>   Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF)."

how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`parent.location = self.location;` is used for reloading the page. Since, you are assigning the location, there is a chance that parameters can also be assigned directly which in-turn can modify database record. So, this might be restricted in your checkmarx.

You can instead use below for refresh:

```
parent.location.reload();
```